# Angular2 Alpha 53 bootstrap not loading properly into SystemJS

Tags: typescript, angular, systemjs

I have created a repo for a sample project using Angular2 Alpha 53.
https://github.com/jyana/Angular2-TypeScript

Within src/app/app.ts I've been forced to link directly to bootstrap:

```
import {bootstrap} from '../../node_modules/angular2/bootstrap.js';
```

I think the correct way to import is:

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/bootstrap';
```

However, that results in a 404 error of not being able to find the bootstrap resource for SystemJS in the console.
"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http: //127.0.0.1:8080/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"

I can't seem to find any resources on this issue.  But some of the other Alpha 53 projects I've seen floating around GitHub do not seem to be using SystemJS.  The only reason I'm using it is because the tutorial on Angular.io was using it but that was for Alpha 46~.

Any thoughts?  Any more information that I can provide that would help get me pointed in the right direction?  Thank you.

Comment: `bootstrap` must be imported from `angular2/platform/browser`. Check the [changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

Comment: Hey Eric.  That did it.  I had checked the changelog because but it didn't specifically list bootstrap as under platform/browser.  Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comments, `bootstrap` is now in `platform/browser`. 

And `Component` is now in `core`:

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
```